# Technical issues when retrieving images using Facebook API call due to the randomized changes in Facebook domain and IP

Tags: facebook, image, api, photo

We are trying to implement a feature for a famous pharmaceutical company website, which requires to retrieve images from facebook using a facebook API, to generate a resultant image file.

However, we are facing technical difficulties retrieving images using API call, due to the randomized changes in domain and IP (sphotos-d.ak.fbcdn.net and a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net ) of the URL from which the image is retrieved (due to CDN, DNS round robin and load balancing). The development environment is rather restricted and opening a wide range of IP addresses is not possible.

Could you kindly advise us of an alternative solution to perform this API call to return a static URL or IP?

More details of our implementation is provided below:

**Function to get image from Facebook:**

```js
function getAlbumPhotos(album_id) {
    var count = 1;
    id = album_id;
    //call FB to get JSON of all photos in an album - the response function is inline
    //and sets the output div  with images and sets up click handlers
    FB.api('/' + id + '/photos', function (response) {
        var nHTML = "";

        //build html for all photos
        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length; i < l; i++) {
            //photo ids
            photo_id = response.data[i];
            //image url
            image_link = photo_id.source
            nHTML += fbPhotos(count, image_link);
            count++;
        }
        //set the html content
        nHTML = "<h1>"+__("select.friend")+"</h1>" + nHTML + "<div class='clear'></div>";
        $('#myContent').html(nHTML);
                                Cufon.refresh();
        //set click handlers for all new items
        for (var i = 0, l = response.data.length+1; i < l; i++) {
            $('#fbphoto_' + i).click(fbPhoto_click);
        }
        hideBusy();
    });
```

The code FB.api('/' + id + '/photos', function (response) {}) The “id” is the album id which user choose. This statement will return the list of image data in json type which contain the image data (Ex. full image url, upload date, title)

The “Full image url” will look like

http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205045_1360429746128_61249_n.jpg

http://sphotos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/308224_1593433971088_1975239922_n.jpg

I use this URL to show image on the client and build the postcard

**Building the Post Card:**

Server (Build the postcard)

```
<?php

$LeftPath = "http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6        /205045_1360429746128_61249_n.jpg";
$RightPath = "http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/205045_1360429746128_61249_n.jpg";
$Postcard = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/Postcard/postcard_BG.jpg');
$LeftImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($LeftPath); 
$RightImage =  imagecreatefromjpeg($RightPath); 
imagealphablending($Postcard, false);
imagesavealpha($Postcard, true);
imagecopymerge($Postcard, $LeftImage, 336, 233, 0, 0, 300, 300, 100);
imagecopymerge($Postcard, $RightImage, 642, 276, 0, 0, 300, 300, 100); 

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($Postcard, NULL, 75);
?>
```

On the server I get the image by “Full image url” from facebook and merge it with the internal postcard image ('images/Postcard/postcard_BG.jpg') using GD Libraly from PHP

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to limit the responses from the API to only include resources on specific servers.

If you need to adjust your firewall so you can reach Facebook's servers, the method to retrieve the full list of IP addresses assigned to Facebook is listed in the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

It's currently retrievable with this command:

> whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route